# WPF Datagrid row validation error not clearing after edit

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, datagrid

Using a DataGrid in WPF, I am trying to get correct behaviour while using error validation via INotifyDataErrorInfo.

I have an ObservableCollection of a class that implements that interface, an bind that collection to the DataGrid. When there is an error, the cell will have a red border, and row will have a red ! in front. All default, all good. When still editing, when the error is gone, the red border and red ! will both disappear. So far, so good!

However, when I leave the row (via keyboard Enter/Tab or with the mouse), then come back it and then remove the error, the red cell border disappears, but the red ! stays.

I am aware this question has been raised before, for example here: [WPF DataGrid validation errors not clearing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5099039/wpf-datagrid-validation-errors-not-clearing). However, the solutions there do not resolve this, apart from hiding the row validation error altogether. (Which, in combination with something like the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2439827/wpf-datagrid-cell-with-validation-error-style) is also quite ok...)

Or is my problem rather that the user is able to leave the editing mode of the cell even though there is a validation error? Preferably, I would like to restrict this, and force the resolution of the error first, before further editing can occur, but I don't know how to enforce this without lots of code...

Here is the XML (the RowValidationErrorTemplate comes from here: [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.rowvalidationerrortemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)):

```
<UserControl x:Class="CustomDG"
             ...etc...
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
             d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance Type=viewmodels:TestViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=testCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
            RowHeight="18" CanUserResizeRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="18" >
            <DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>
              <ControlTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="0,-2,0,-2"
                    ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource
                    FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}},
                    Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}">
                    <Ellipse StrokeThickness="0" Fill="Red" 
                        Width="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                        Height="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" />
                    <TextBlock Text="!" FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}" 
                        FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" 
                        HorizontalAlignment="Center"  />
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowValidationErrorTemplate>-->

            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, 
                    ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors=True, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" >
                </DataGridTextColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you need to raise **notifyPropertyChanged** with empty string after row committed or canceled edit to refresh the DataBinding From object and this will refresh your interface use it like that:

```
RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("");
```

Comment: how to implament that? Can i have an full example of using that?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Validation.ErrorsProperty on DataGridRow is accumulating errors every time I leave "add new row" edit if there is an error in any cell. Horrible mechanism.

Comment: That is why I am using control for edit and not DataGrid, it's unimaginably clunky! I just don't see the logic behind this behavior, is it a bug or what?